# how to create memory aligned buffer in python like posix_memalign in C

Tags: python, linux, memory

I want to create posix_memalign buffer like C in Python

I used to use [mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) to create memory aligned buffer in python

but I can't create more mem aligned buffers as possible when I use 32-bit ubuntu.

because I only can get **2G mem aligned buffer totally** in **32-bit** machine.

Is there anyway to replace mmap with another library in Python?

Here is my test code in 32-bit machine

```
import mmap

blk = 50*512*1024
def get_buf():
        data = '\0'*blk
        buf=mmap.mmap(-1, blk, mmap.MAP_SHARED)
        buf.seek(0)
        buf.write(data)
        return buf

a=[]
for i in range(0, 4096):
        try:
                a.append(get_buf())
        except Exception as e:
                print i # will break when i = 77
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.
The root cause is I run in 32-bit machine, and process can get map virtual memory address at most 3GB(mmap map data to virtual memory).

Don't care about stack, syscall...etc used by process, the process almost map virtual memory 2~2.5GB.

Additionally, call mmap.close() will free the virtual address and then I have free space to call mmap again.
so reasons below:

1. **32bit machine virtual address limit**
2. **Forget to call mmap.close() after use mmap buffer.**

Solution:

1. **reuse the mmap buffer**
2. **find some way to create aligned meomry buffer(I found nothing else)**

welcome to answer if anyone find better ways